# Correct way in OOP. Game example. Player::walk or Map::playerWalk?

Tags: c++, oop, class-design

Let's suppose there is a game. There is a map class and a player class. Map stores fields and fields stores players.
Which would be a proper way to do in OOP. When method responsible for player walking would be Player::walk or Map::playerWalk?

Concerning first example (Player::walk), it seems that it is correct way to do and its like in real life - its player who walks,
however it would have to access destination field through map instance, check if it can walk there, remove its from start field and add its on destination field, I have impression that Player would "know too much".

Comment: It would be about equivalent to the knowledge a "player" would have in real life.  They should know not to walk directly into a wall!

Comment: You have a 3rd possibility: a free function: `PlayerWalk(Player, Map)`.

Comment: @Jarod42; not really possible with OOP though... (possible as in preferable, and really not possible with a true class oriented language, such as java and C#)

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig Free function algorithms are an extremely common idiom in C++ (as this question is tagged).

Comment: I would put this in the object that handles the game logic (i.e. "none of the above").

Comment: @Mark B, I'm well aware, but it's still not a (good) OOP practice. You're still correct, it is a 3rd *possibility*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately this is a design question, both could fit well within the OOP paradigm.

I tend to place methods on the class that makes the most sense semantically. In this scenario, that means `Player::walk`, unless the map does something to make "players" move (I.e. in a flippers game, the game board makes the ball [aka 'player'] move) and then it may be more semantic to have that entity call for instance `Board::movePlayer`.

You should pass the map instance to the player if you go for the `Player::walk` design. So you end up with `Player::walk(Map &map /*more parameters here, maybe a direction or vector speed?*/)`.

The other thing to point out is that you should try to *tell* more than you *ask*. What this means is that rather than:

```
//in Player::walk
if (map.cells[wantToWalkTo] == 0) {
    map.cells[wantToWalkTo] = this.playerId;
}
//TODO: handle failed moves
```

You should do something like:

```
bool moved = map.moveTo(position, this); //encapsulate the logic for moving a player to a position
//TODO: handle failed moves
```

Answer (score 1):

Your player instance doesn't have to "know" all those things. It can communicate with the Map instance through an interface. A person can look out at their surroundings and see some things, but not others (e.g. can see a wall, but not what's behind it). The Map instance can be in control of what is visible and what isn't.

Python-ish pseudo-code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, Map, location):
        """Create a player, and tell them what Map they live on."""
        self.Map = Map
        self.location = location

    def walk(self, destination):
        """Try to walk to the destination."""
        path = self.Map.path_visible(location, destination)

        if path:
            self.location = destination

class Map:
    def path_visible(self, location, destination):
        """Can a player at location see how to get to the destination?"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct OOP approach would be for the map to present some kind of interface which would allow to:

1. Check whether some field is empty / what object is on that field
2. Place objects on the map / remove them

The logic of moving the player should be entirely in the Player class. So checking whether target field is reachable by the player, whether is empty, etc... should be handled by the Player using information provided by the Map interface or other classes. Consider for example situation when you would like to allow player to walk through walls, walk on water or similar stuff - it's the player who changes, not the map!